# Jquery Mobile Issues with Disabling Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

So I am using jquery mobile for an admin interface for something I am doing. Multiple people will be using this interface in real time. I realized that after a page has been loaded into the DOM, it doesn't change. So if someone changes a value on the server the page will not change unless you manually refresh the browser. This is a problem. So I tried to put this in my head on my HTML

```
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
```

But to no avail. I think I need to disable ajax or clear out the DOM on every request or something. Does anyone have any idea on why this isn't working or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: remove `.ready()` dont use in jQM. Moreover, `mobileinit` fires before `.ready()`.

Comment: Ok. I tried that. Still no luck.

Comment: Are you using multi page template or several HTML pages? And if you are using several HTML pages is this page part of your first HTML or subsequent ones?

Comment: I am not using multipage templates I am using several HTML pages. I don't understand the second question.

Comment: I am using rails and an application layout. Could that be contributing to my grief?